# Mysql backup size decreasing on each automated backup?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, backup, database-backups

I am running automated daily backups of a mysql database and haven't done any changes on my site since December. The size of the backups seems to be decreasing everyday, and I don't feel that's right. Lemme know if you need me to provide more info. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a full backup every day and you aren't writing to a partition that isn't already full?

Comment: Well, it seems to be a full backup of the site including the database. I was able to recover one of those backups and it works perfectly just that I don't know if there may be missing content.

Comment: You could try using a tool like Percona's pt-table-checksum against the current copy and the restored backup. That would give you a row count for each table which might help to identify where row counts were changing. If you use the --databases switch you can target the specific databases e.g. pt-table-checksum --databases currentdb,restoreddb. Or, run it daily and compare the numbers.